# Appsee 2.5.0 version

Tags: ios, cocoapods, appsee

So I'm trying to install the Appsee 2.5.0 because we want to install the "wireframe only" version.

So I go into the pods and added:

`pod 'Appsee', '~> 2.5.0'`

But when I run `pod install` or `pod update` it install the `2.5.1` version.

Why I need the 2.5.0?
I don't want the video recording, I just want the wireframe feature.

Comment: Version 2.5.1 supports both modes: 'wireframe only' and video recording, according to the [docs](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/native).

Comment: I know, but the company didn't certified the 2.5.1 version... bureaucracy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `2.5.1` because the `~>` [means](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) "the latest version from 2.5.0, but less than 2.6.0". If you want a specific version, or don't need 2.5.x, then you can specify an *exact* version by dropping the `~>`.

`pod 'Appsee', '2.5.0'`

You can read more about semantics of versioning in [CocoaPods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)

Comment: To specify: pod 'Appsee', '2.5.0'